# Show related answers when answering community wiki questions

Tags: feature-request, answers, community-wiki

**Related answers to the same question** could be displayed while you are answering a community wiki question.

This would encourage collaboratively improving (if needed) a very similar answer, instead of adding something which may be a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking and answering a question in which you would potentially have a list of related questions and answers to look through to make sure you are not duplicating...your bigger concern should be about the fact that you are duplicating info and not that the information is not immediately available.

If someone is asking a question similar to another and the answer is something that is likely to be the same answer as the previous question, you likely have yourself a duplicate and it should be closed instead of answered.

I don't see what the point of differentiating CW questions is for.

Comment: I was talking about very similar answers to the same question, not to other questions. I edited to clarify.

Comment: if you are looking for similar answers, look through the question before trying to answer. If you already looked and you are afraid someone will post something new that matches, you should get one of those warnings at the top of the screen that new answers have been posted. Load those new answers and make sure they aren't different. I don't see why you are looking for a way to look for things when there are multiple ways to do it easily already.

Comment: Not so easily, if you have five pages of answers.

Comment: @Daniel: If it has already so many answers, than your answer will probably not add any value. Very likely it's a poll and no-one cares, if it has 100 or 101 "answers".